# Highlight Row in Salesforce Report

Tags: community

I created tabular report group by one colum (Region), the report contain two formula fields from the object that contain boolean value.One named '7 Day Left', another one name 'The date is over'.

The user request to have yellow hightlight for row if '7 Day Left' column is true, and red highlight row  for 'The date is over colum.'Currently the report already served the purpose except highlighting.

I read [Conditional Highlight in Report](http://www.infallibletechie.com/2014/09/conditional-highlighting-in-reports-in.html) , but it only applicable for Summary and Metric and also I am not sure how to make it read from Object's formula field?

Is there anyone know trick doing this?Or do I need to forget doing it in Standard Report and start coding from the scratch just to display report?

*Edited:
I already change to Summary Report but it seem Conditional Highlight is disabled for me.Any idea?

[image]

Comment: Okay, now I got it.Need to create two formula for these two boolean fields.Let me try first and update you later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a workaround, although it is not perfect. Sharing it so you can assess whether it's enough to prevent you from having to custom-build it..

In order to use conditional highlighting as a standard reports feature, you indeed need to turn your report into a Summary Report. But as you mention you are grouping by Region, that automatically makes your report a Summary Report already.

Next, you can only highlight summary rows. But obviously you want to keep the individual records. So to do that you could use the trick of grouping by record id (or any other unique field) as the second level grouping after region.

Then add the checkbox formula fields to the report and 'summarize by' the fields, e.g. calculating the sum (true will count as 1, false as 0).

Additionally, you could 'summarize by' any other fields you require in the summary rows of the report. Not all fields will be eligible, though, so the end use might have to go into details to view all data on a record.

Lastly, add the conditional highlighting for the 2 checkbox summary fields.

You might want to 'hide details'  by default for the report. Depends on what data the user wants to see.